# There is blank space present at the top of website page

Tags: html, css, web

I am creating a web page. Even though i have added margin:0px and padding:0px still some blank space is present at the top of my web page. here is my css code for body section.Any solutions?Thanx in advance..

```
<html >
    <head>
       <style>

        html {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }
        #navR
        {float:right;
        margin-right:0px;
        }
        #mR{
        float: right;
        }
        .bodyl{
         height: 100%;  
        background-color: #F8FADE;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size:15px;
        margin:0px;
        top: -22px; 
         clear: both;
        }
        .local{
            background-color:#DEB887;
            margin-left:0px;
            margin-right:0px;
            margin-top:0px;
            margin-bottom:0px;
            padding:0px;
            width:100%;
            vertical-align: baseline;
            }
            .heading{
            font-size: 250%;
            color:#5B3205;
            margin-top:10px;

            font-style: oblique;    
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="local">
            <p id="mR"><strong>My name</strong></p>
            <h3 id="navR"> <a>logout</a> </h3>
            <h1 class="heading">My space</h1>
        </div> </br>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `top: -22px` could be an issue. Is it about 22 pixels of blank space at the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `<h1>` tag. This text has a default margin set by the browser. You can set a `margin-top: 0px` in your `.heading` class. That will fix the problem.

edit: In your case you should replace `margin-top: 10px` with  `margin-top: 0px`

Answer (score -1):

Please also set margin to 0 on your html attribute

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Then it should work perfectly for you, as it does for me. It could also be possible that you have a child attribute that has a certain margin and so it could lead to that white space.